# Subscribing i18n to mobx, translate based on observable react

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, mobx

I am using i18n to supply translations to my project, currently it will translate based on browser language. I want it to instead of that change the language based on a property in a mobx store.

I have tried looking into `react-mobx-i18n`, and it seems like a bad solution. Because I would have to annotate every single component as translatable and restructure everything.

```js
import i18n from 'i18next'

i18n
    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        resources: {

        },
        ns: ['application'],
        defaultNS: 'application',

        react: {
            wait: true,
        },
    })

export default i18n
```

here is the render of my App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next'
import i18n from './i18n'
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react'

export default class App extends Component {

 render() {

        return (
            <Provider {...this.props.stores}> //mobx stores
                <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}> 
                //router want to change mobx-state and rerender everything with a new language
                </I18nextProvider>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to somehow make i18n subscribe to my mobx state and update when a new language is detected. Should this be impossible, then I would like to write a handler in a store to change the language based on some input.